# Return early from a trigger in order to skip the logic

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I want to skip a trigger that gets called when a table gets updated.  I know that if the UserID of the updated row is below a certain ID I can skip it.

The `inserted` table can have multiple rows, when will it have multiple rows?  Since a trigger fires on an update, won't the trigger get called for each row in the update?

Is the below SQL correct to ignore the trigger. If the ID is less than 123, I want the trigger to just `RETURN` and skip the logic it would normally do:

```
DECLARE @UserID AS INT = (SELECT UserID FROM Inserted)
IF @UserID <= 123
BEGIN
    RETURN
END
```

Comment: What do you want to happen if the `inserted` table contains some rows that are less than 123, and some that are greater than 123?

Comment: added a where clause, ```select * from inserted where userID > 123```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server [triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/dml-triggers?view=sql-server-2017) fire once per statement, not once per row.  And a statement can affect any number of rows.

So you will have to execute your normal trigger logic and simply take no action for any rows that have a `UserId <= 123`.

Comment: I see, so ```DECLARE @UserID  AS INT = (SELECT UserID FROM Inserted)``` will not work then right?  I should do ```SELECT TOP 1 UserID FROM inserted``` then?

Comment: No.  You must code the trigger to expect multiple rows in Inserted, any subset of which cold have a `UserID <= 123`.

Answer (score 1):

If you know without a doubt that all rows being updated will contain the same `UserID` you can shortcut out of the trigger using:

```
if exists (select 1 from Inserted where UserId <= 123) return;
```

That is potentially very dangerous because if there is ever a mixed update containing both UserId <= 123 and UserId > 123 the trigger will not run for those > 123. And consider while your app may never do that, a DBA might from SSMS to manually correct some data.

The correct way to handle this situation is as follows:

```
declare @Id int, @UserId int;
declare @Rows table (Id int, UserId int);

insert into @Rows (Id, UserId)
  select Id, UserId from Inserted;

while exists (select 1 from @Rows) begin
  select top 1 @Id = Id, @UserId = UserId from @Rows;
  if @UserId > 123 begin
    -- Do stuff
  end
  delete from @Rows where Id = @Id;
end
```

It should be noted that where possible you should avoid this kind of row-by-row based activity as it is an anti-database-pattern and could cause performance issues. Ideally all database operations would be set based.